# google app engine, budget is short warning script

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a critical app running on GAE. I had 2 cases, when I went over budget.
I have tests warning me when I loose the website, but I'd love to get an earlier notification, when my buget is running out. 
Is there a way to access the daily budget estination, so I can send myself a warning before it becomes a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for this purpose sorry, your best bet right now (if it's that important) is parsing the quota page.

[A ticket](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655) was opened a few years back, it's acknowledged but no news.

Comment: Well, that's not the answer I was hoping for, but it is an answer. Thanks